# how to map table to class in Doctrine with php

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

Hi I am new to PHP and Doctrine I am trying to follow through with [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html) tutorial:

I defined class Person at the root of project
( in the database I had table Person like class Person)...I was trying to get person name for some id..I was not able to do the part of $paths and $path correctly and got compile errors...so commented those parts and executed the program....the result somehow was deletion of Person table in db.
my code as follows:`

```html
<?php
echo "hellooo";
// bootstrap.php
// Include Composer Autoload (relative to project root).
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
require "person.php";
$paths = array("/path/to/entity-files");
$isDevMode = false;
// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => 'phpFundamentals',
    'password' => 'phpFundamentals',
    'dbname' => 'phpfundamentals'
);
$path ="Person";// 'path/to/entities';
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

$person = new Person();
$person->setName('ali');
$person->setAge(50);

$entityManager->persist($person);
$entityManager->flush();




//$person = $entityManager->find("Person", $id);
//echo $person;
```

So how do I set $paths and $path? so that person table can be created in db.
or data can be retrieved from existing table `

Comment: maybe this link can help you? http://ormcheatsheet.com/